# Launch application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to launch an application using win32 ...

Please let me know your ideas to achieve this

Comment: C/C++? C#? VB? More information always helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (approximately) ascending order of control and complexity: `WinExec`, `ShellExecute`, `ShellExecuteEx`, `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) (It can launch any filetype and will handle elevation) If you need more control of the new process, use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: CreateProcess can fail on applications that require elevation, we have no clue what kind of process we are starting here so it is probably not the best choice.